# Codeigniter - Hook to log GET / POST REQUESTS

Tags: codeigniter, post, logging, get, hook

A client requires that all GET/POST requests are logged and stored for 90 days for their applicaiton. I have written a HOOK which seems to record some of the GETS / POSTS but there is less data than I would expect. For example, when submitting form data, the entries don't seem to be put in the log. Has anyone written something similar which works?

Here is my version thus far:

```
class Logging {

    function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->CI->load->model('Logging_m');
        $this->CI->load->model('Portal_m');

        //get POST and GET values for LOGGING        
        $post = trim(print_r($this->CI->input->post(), TRUE));
        $get = trim(print_r($this->CI->input->get(), TRUE));

        $this->CI->Logging_m->logPageView(array(
                'portal_id' => $this->CI->Portal_m->getPortalId(),
                'user_id' => (!$this->CI->User_m->getUserId() ? NULL : $this->CI->User_m->getUserId()),
                'domain' => $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"],
                'page' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                'post' => $post,
                'get' => $get,
                'ip' => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
                'datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ));
    }

}
```

This data is stored in a model called 'Logging_m' which looks like this:

```
<?php 
class Logging_m extends CI_Model {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function logPageView($data) {
    $this->db->insert('port_logging', $data);
  }

}

/* End of file logging_m.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/logging_m.php */
```

Comment: can you post the form your are missing its actions.

Comment: Interesting question +1. Can you do a var_dump of your form input and post it next to the log for the same input so we can play spot the difference.

Comment: Are all of your array values being set like you expect, or is it only the GET/POST info? Also,I am just curious, why are you using print_r to return the $_POST array when $this->input->post() is already returning the data. You don't seem to be cleaning the data, only trimming it. It just seems redundant.

Comment: You should use a hook for that. Probably 'pre_controller': http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Also better use $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: Hmm, I just see that my answer below is kind of what you already had. I didn't read your post well enough. Normally using a hook it should log all the requests that pass the CI_Controller.

Answer (score 17):

As mentionned by Patrick Savalle you should use hooks. Use the `post_controller_constructor` hook so you can use all other CI stuff.

1) In `./application/config/config.php` set `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE`

2) In `./application/config/hooks.php` add the following hook

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'Http_request_logger',
    'function' => 'log_all',
    'filename' => 'http_request_logger.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array()
);
```

3) Create the file `./application/hooks/http_request_logger.php` and add the following code as example.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Http_request_logger {

    public function log_all() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('info', 'GET --> ' . var_export($CI->input->get(null), true));
        log_message('info', 'POST --> ' . var_export($CI->input->post(null), true));                
        log_message('info', '$_SERVER -->' . var_export($_SERVER, true));
    }

}
```

I've tested it and it works for me (make sure you have logging activated in your config file).

Comment: is it OK to declare $CI as public in a hook file?

Comment: @VipinKr.Singh Looking at it again I don't see any reason to declare it outside the function at all. I've modified the example.

Comment: Nothing is writing in info page neither page is created from your code. :(

Comment: @BikashP I can assure you it worked for me 2 years ago (I only put tested code on SO). Also the fact that it was already marked 7 times as useful answer probably means it works. You're for sure missing something else in your code on your side.