# How to log every GET And POST data in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

I have a Server on which many IOS and Android Client send HTTP request, and based on that request i send them some response back.

Now I want to store all the incoming request in my logs so it can be helpful for debugging. Also i want to store what my server sent back in response.

**The Request i get on server:**

```
$data = $this->license_m->array_from_get(array('request','device_id','product','software_version','platform_os','platform_model','platform'));
```

**The Response Server gives back**

```
 $response = array(
                     'response_code' =>200 ,
                         'request'=> $this->input->get('request'),
                     'device_id'=> $this->input->get('device_id'),
                     'allowed_hours'=> $remaining_hours,
                     'product'=>'mlc',
                     'url'=>NULL
                 );

                return $this->output
                ->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

Now i want to log all this data into logs of my codeigniter. How to do that?

I tried this :

```
log_message('debug',print_r($data,TRUE));
```

but this saves either request array or the response array not both of them

My License Class
:

```
<?php

/**
*
*/
class License extends Admin_Controller
{

 public function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct();

     $this->load->model('license_m');
 }

 public function index($id = NULl)
 {

     $req = $this->input->get('request');



     if($req =="trial")
     {
        $request = array(
         'request' => $this->input->get('request'),
         'device_id' => $this->input->get('device_id'),
         'launch_date'=> $this->input->get('launch_date'),
         'allowed_hours'=>$this->input->get('trial_usage'),

         'product'=>$this->input->get('product'),
         'software_version'=> $this->input->get('software_version'),
         'platform_os'=> $this->input->get('platform_os'),
         'platform'=> $this->input->get('platform'),
         'platform_model'=> $this->input->get('platform_model')
             );



        /* checking if device id exists */
          $data = $this->license_m->array_from_get(array('request','device_id','product','software_version','platform_os','platform_model','platform'));

  $this->db->where('device_id',$data['device_id']);
  $this->db->where('request','activation');

  $query = $this->db->get('activation');


 $response = array(
                             'response_code' =>200 ,
                             'device_id'=> $this->input->get('device_id'),
                             'expiry_date'=> '20201231-235959',
                             'product'=>'mlc',
                             'url'=>NULL ,
                             'request'=> $this->input->get('request')


                             );


                             return $this->output
                             ->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json')
                             ->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: Use the hook concept in codeigniter

Comment: Have you tried looking into the `Apache` or `nginx` logs that may already have the information you are looking for? `apache` logs are usually in the `/var/log/` folder.

Comment: @VairaMuthu how will hooks help me in this ?

Comment: @PrahladYeri  but i dont want every apache logs i just want to save some specifc information that i can use for debugging my application

Comment: @Rajan My point being that your apache logs might already be storing this information, logging is turned on by default on most production servers. Have you tried checking that?

Comment: Yeah @PrahladYeri  i checked it. But when working on Cpanel i cant always go an check apache logs better i create my own logs for CI

Comment: @Rajan Refer the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195291/codeigniter-hook-to-log-get-post-requests

Answer (score 2):

You could override the CI_Output

```
class MY_Output extends CI_Output {
    public function _display($output = '') {
        log_message('debug', '[Request: '.@json_encode(get_instance()->get_post(null)).'][Response: '.@json_encode($output).']');

        return parent::_display($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but how do i use this? i mean my json output is in some class called License now how will i log its data ?

Comment: @Rajan well I'm going to need to see this License class

Comment: @Rajan sorry, but I don't see where you output the json

Comment: @Rajan The way I see it, your License controller class is using Codeigniter's CI_Output class for writing your response,

    $this->output
                             ->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json')
                             ->set_output(json_encode($response))

Internally, CI_Output will end up calling it's _display method, and since you're overriding it, you will get all the outputs

Comment: how will  i logs these request and resposne array into logs

Comment: @Rajan If I'm not mistaken, you creating the file MY_Output.php in application/core directory and placing that code, should achieve the loggings, please try it and if it's not working you can chat me