# How to log every GET And POST data in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

my web application is doing a lot of AJAX calls (GET and POST) to our CodeIgniter 4 backend. My current approach to debug the AJAX call is setting manual logging messages within every method. Too time-consuming.

Do you know if there is a better way to do that? Overwriting a CI class?

I am happy about every help.

Comment: log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');

Comment: This is what I am doing right now. It's a lot extra code and too time-consuming. You have to add this statement to every method. There has to be a better away to make it more dynamic like this -> overwriting CI_Output -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170135/how-to-log-every-get-and-post-data-in-codeigniter In this post they are using an older CI version. I don't know how to do this with CI4.

Comment: I think creating an after filter and make that filter applies on the route you want is a path to explore : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logging the request you have to create the "after filters".

First You Define the Class which implements FilterInterface.

```
    class Logger implements FilterInterface
    {
        use ResponseTrait;
    
    public function before(RequestInterface $request)
        {
         ...   
        }
    
    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
        {
           ...
        }
    
    }
```

In the after method, you will need to store the response and then save it using log_message.

```
public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $response_service = \Config\Services::response();
         log_message('info', '{message}', ['message' => $response_service->getJSON()]

    }
```

Here, I have stored used the response service explicitly and then simply called the getJSON to store the JSON body of the request. You will need to modify this for your problem. Also, do note you don't need to call the response service explicitly. There was another thread that showed how you can save the response implicitly, so you might want to refer to that.

Once the filter is done, you need to register the alias for the routes as below :

```
public $aliases = ['logger'         =>  \App\Filters\Logger::class];
```

Once done you can either implement on individual routes or global routes.
Below is how you can implement it on global routes:

```
public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        ...
    ],
    'after'  => [
        'logger',
    ],
];
```

References : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html?highlight=filter

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/request.html?highlight=request

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/logging.html?highlight=log_message

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats great! I just checked and noticed that this approach just works for Controllers. Is there a way to log Models and Custom Classes as well?

Comment: In MVC architecture, logging is done at the point of Controllers. You can log custom classes and models as well. There are two ways on doing so, either use a Repository pattern where the Base Repository is integrated with the logging mechanism, or you can create a master Model which is integrated with the logging mechanism and you can extend this to other classes. But all the logging can be achieved from the Controller itself in my experience (including the errors thrown by Model and Custom Classes). For example Model A has failed validations, these can be logged when sending the response.

Answer (score -1):

Just use
echo $this->request->getPost("usersemail"); die();
for usersemail input field